# Error pagina en blanco laravel en hosting

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

Tengo los archivos de mi página web desarrollada en laravel en mis hosting, por alguna razón cuando direcciono el index.php que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta public_html, no se carga la página, queda en blanco. Reviso y la pestaña de red en herramientas de desarrollador del navegador y me doy cuenta que es un error 500. Al revisar el error_log de mi hosting me dice los siguiente:

```
[16-Jul-2017 21:03:03] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\'   (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home3/sqngolfc/public_html/index.php on line 49
[16-Jul-2017 21:03:03] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home3/sqngolfc/public_html/index.php on line 49
```

Mi versión de php es 5.6.29

Mi index.php es:

```
<?php

/**
* Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
*
* @package  Laravel
* @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../markuno/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../markuno/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Mi .htaccess es:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

La version de php segun composer es "php": ">=5.6.4"
No se si esto tenga algo que ver.

Comment: Me parece extraño que el error indique que hay un problema en la línea 49 del index, cuando el código que muestras del archivo no llega a superar las 20 líneas.

Comment: Lo resumí para evitar informaación innecesario, pero lo prondré como lo tengo exactamente.

Comment: Puede ser que la versión que te muestra la consola no sea la misma que está utilizando Laravel. Prueba colocar en un archivo PHP `phpinfo();` y verificar la versión que tienes.

Comment: La versión que me sale en el servidor es la 5.6.29 y la que usa laravel es la 5.6.4, creo que debo actualizar la del servidor. Lo haré y despues les comento que tal funcionó

Comment: ¿Hiciste un `phpinfo()`? 5.6.29 es más reciente que 5.6.4, así que no tienes que actualizar nada, tienes que verificar que en la carpeta public de Laravel se esté utilizando dicha versión y no una inferior a 5.6

Comment: ¿Me puedes dar la fuente donde puedo corroborrar esta información?

Comment: ¿Corroborar qué información?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría siempre usar la versión mínima de 7.0 de PHP.

¿Como has hecho el "deploy" de la aplicación? ¿Vía FTP? ¿Has hecho un `composer install` para verificar que todos los paquetes necesarios están instalados?

¿Has revisado que la versión de PHP de la terminal sea la misma que con la que estas ejecutando la web? Algunos paneles de control (Plesk por ejemplo) tiene diferentes versiones para la terminal que para la ejecución de PHP de la web.

Puedes verlo mejor con un `<?php phpinfo() ?>`.

En caso de que eso no sea el problema, por favor, danos más información sobre el servidor, versiones de PHP, si tiene panel o no,etc.

Comment: El composer install lo hice cuando estaba desarrolando la aplicación, el dashboard de bluehost me dice que tiene la versión de php 5.6.29, pero el archivo composer.json de mi aplicación me dice que estoy utilizando en mi proyecto php 5.6.4, subí los archivos al servidor mediante cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue actualizar la versión de php ejecutandose en el servidor, mediente el cpanel.

Answer (score -1):

este error me pasó hace poco y creo que puede tener muchas causas, pero en mi caso particular era porque en el archivo .env había colocado una contraseña con espacios en blanco, cuando me di cuenta cambié la contraseña y el error estaba resuelto.

No olvides limpiar la cache con php artisan config:cache.